# a map in $R$-Mod is injective iff it is a monomorphism

Tags: category-theory, modules, monomorphisms

I would like to see a detailed argument of this fact:

a map in $R$-Mod is injective iff it is a monomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monomorphism are preserved by right adjoint functors and reflected by faithful functors. The forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}_R \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ satisfies both properties.

**Edit** the down-to-earth way is to note that a monomorphism $f:M \rightarrow N$ in $\mathsf{Mod}_R$ is precisely a morphism satisfying $\ker f = 0$ and that this is equivalent to $f$ being injective. Indeed applying the monomorphism property to the two morphisms $R \overset{0}{\rightarrow} M$ and $R \overset{m}{\rightarrow} M, 1 \mapsto m$ for any element $m \in \ker f$ shows $\ker f = 0$. As $f$ not injective implies $\ker f \neq 0$ by taking the difference of two distinct elements mapping to the same, we find that monomorphisms are injective. The converse direction feels cleanest by using the faithful argument, but can be done in a similarly elementary way.

Comment: I was looking for an elementary argument not invoking more complicated stuff like adjointeness.

Comment: You tagged category-theory, so I thought this would help. Anyway I will edit.

Comment: Adjointness is not complicated stuff! It's one of the most fundamental concepts in category theory!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I wholeheartedly agree. But assuming Op doesn’t really know much category theory, I can relate with adjoints feeling complicated. It takes time getting used to work with categories ...